# For primarily running Xcode is the processor or RAM more important?

Tags: memory, cpu, xcode, macbook-air

I'm going to be purchasing a Macbook Air. I'm a developer and all I'll use the computer for is Xcode. Should I be more concerned with upgrading the RAM or the CPU?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some **sick** soldering skills upgrading the CPU isn't even an option.

The processors on *most* Apple Laptops are soldered to the logic board. What you buy is what you're more or less stuck with, providing you don't purchase a new logic board with an upgrade CPU.
Hard Drive upgrades and RAM upgrades are the DIY'ables. I recommend at least upgrading the RAM.

**P.S.** *If you're looking for power in an AppleBook I wouldn't recommend the air.*

Answer (score 0):

RAM will most likely be more important, as Xcode tends to use more and more as you leave it open. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14924/49229 for a detailed description.